# Loop through pyspark dataframe once to find rows that contains list of values

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe similar to below in pyspark

| ProjectName | ProjectNumber |
| --- | --- |
| TBD Canada | 10000000000029 |
| TBD China | 10000000000033 |
| TBD United States | 10000000000974 |
| US Diver | 10000000000234 |
| Flower 2.0 | 10000000023947 |

I need to extract the country from ProjectName that contain TBD.
I also have a list of country name from my dimension table
`country_list = ['Canada','United States',....., 'China']`
I have about 75 countries in this list

I initially tried solving it by using a for loop, I wrote the following

```
country_list = ['Canada','United States',....., 'China']
# Set initial ExtractCountry column
df = df.withColumn("ExtractColumn", lit(None).cast("string"))
# Loop through data frame
for country in country_list:
    df = df.withColumn("ExtractColumn", when(df.ProjectName.contains("TBD") 
                                             & df.ProjectName.contains(country), lit(country))
                                       .otherwise(F.col("ExtractColumn")))
```

It works but it takes a really long time to run since my df is so big and that means it runs length of dataframe x 75 countries. I know pyspark doesn't have indexing like pandas dataframe (I have to use pyspark can't use pandas) but is there anyway for me to loop through dataframe only once or some other way to reduce runtime?

Comment: You need to distribute the work. Put `country_list` in a dataframe with one column country. Then join/merge/union with `df`, which will all scale where a for loop does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove the `TBD` from `projectname` with [`regexp_replace`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('ExtractColumn', F
        .when(F.col('projectname').startswith('TBD'), F.regexp_replace('projectname', 'TBD ', ''))
    )
    .show(10, False)
)

# Output
# +------------------+--------------+--------------+
# |projectname       |projectnumber |ExtractColumn |
# +------------------+--------------+--------------+
# |TBD Canada        |10000000000029|Canada        |
# |TBD China         |10000000000033|China         |
# |TBD United Kingdom|10000000000033|United Kingdom|
# |US Diver          |10000000000234|null          |
# |Flower 2.0        |10000000023947|null          |
# +------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: what about when a country name is more than one word? is there a way to take all the split values except TBD?

Comment: I was actually thinking split might not a good idea, updated my answer with `regex_replace` instead.

Comment: didn't know about this function. thank you! life saviour

Comment: np, I updated the document link, there are many more functions you can read there. Also, feel free to accept the answer if you found it helpful :)